# How do you choose the desired input before starting Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I usually leave my USB joypad always connected to the PC, but Skyrim decides that it should be the main input, so I am enforced to disconnect it before start to play.

Is there a setting that I can define to always use keyboard/mouse as main input without disconnecting joypad?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a setting in `SkyrimPrefs.ini` that you can define before starting Skyrim.

Under `[MAIN]` section `bGamepadEnable=0` disable the joypad `bGamepadEnable=1` enable it.

Comment: Make sure you edit the file in `C:\Users\...\Documents\My Games\Skyrim`  the one in the game folder did not seem to make a difference for me.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, it automatically picky my Gamepad as input on first starting Skyrim. There was an option called "360 Controller" in the System->Settings menu, after disabling it Skyrim defaults to mouse and keyboard on every start.

Comment: I can't open the game right now, the menu and option names are from memory, they might be slightly different.

Comment: SYSTEM > SETTINGS > 360 Controller