# Prevent keyboard and mouse from being disabled when using controller

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Is there a way (outside of using external software such as xpadder or GlovePIE) to use both a controller and mouse/keyboard in Skyrim?

[This similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34986/how-do-you-choose-the-desired-input-before-starting-skyrim/35151#35151) covers disabling the gamepad so that the mouse and keyboard can be used. However, I want to also be able to use the gamepad, and swap to keyboard/mouse without having to go into the menus.

Setting `bGamepadEnable` in SkyrimPrefs.ini to `0` just allows me to use the keyboard in the main menu, but does not allow me to use the keyboard during gameplay.

Comment: If you are still looking, check out http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/27914/?. It's a bit old, and the description a little lacking, but it might be worth a try. Haven't tried it, because the zip file is broken for me, but that might be a network issue (it has happened in the past for me, ENB is also corrupted everytime for me). If it works, be sure to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this mod out: [Use both Xbox 360 controller AND Keyboard SIMULTANEOUSLY](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/30913/?).

> This text file lets you use your Xbox 360 controller and your keyboard simultaneously. This is perfect if you like to use VAC while also playing with your Xbox 360 controller. For this, you have to enable the controller in the settings menu.
>
> What I did was use Xpadder to map the left button to \"End\" and set my VAC push to talk key as \"End\", and set it to \"Arm\" mode. So all you have to do is click the left button during gameplay and say the command to execute it.

The screenshot below explains a bit more.

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with preventing the mouse and keyboard from being disabled?

Comment: +1, this is along the lines of what I'm looking for. However, the mouse is still disabled with this.